# Tomcat Java web application not connecting to MySQL when routed through virtual host

Tags: mysql, apache, tomcat, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

My Java/JSP/Spring Web application running on Tomcat runs fine on my EC2 instance when using the url in the form: www.mydomain.com:8080/my-webapp/ However, when I try to set up a virtual host for it on apache2 by editing 000-default.conf in etc/apache2/sites-enabled -- the application still runs, this time as www.mydomain.com, but only up to the page where it has to hit the MySQL database to log in a user. The database query returns the page:

HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.70

My 000-default.conf file reads:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off

    ServerAdmin ubuntu@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/my-webapp/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/my-webapp/

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

#vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I admit I don't understand the 000-default.conf and am grateful for any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Mapping `/` to `/my-webapp` is not recommended because it requires you do to a huge amount of work to re-write every URL that might be in a page. It's better to do either of these:

```
ProxyPass /my-webapp/ http://localhost:8080/my-webapp/
ProxyPassReverse /my-webapp/ http://localhost:8080/my-webapp/
```

or re-name your web application from `my-webapp` to `ROOT` (upper case is important) and then do this:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

In either case, you'll have much better luck.